# Passing a list or array to RESTeasy using get

Tags: arrays, rest, get, resteasy

I've seen this kind of thing described in various examples showing how to create a REST service which takes arrays or a list of objects as part of the URL.

My question is, how to implement this using RESTeasy?
Something like the following would be how i would assume this to work.

```
   @GET
   @Path("/stuff/")
   @Produces("application/json")
    public StuffResponse getStuffByThings(
            @QueryParam("things") List<Thing> things);
```

Answer (score 3):

Create a [StringConverter](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.3.1.GA/userguide/html_single/index.html#StringConverterInterface) and a use a wrapper object. Here is a quick and dirty example:

```
public class QueryParamAsListTest {
public static class Thing {
    String value;
     Thing(String value){ this.value = value; }
}

public static class ManyThings {
    List<Thing> things = new ArrayList<Thing>();

    ManyThings(String values){
        for(String value : values.split(",")){
            things.add(new Thing(value));
        }
    }
}

static class Converter implements StringConverter<ManyThings> {

    public ManyThings fromString(String str) {
        return new ManyThings(str);
    }

    public String toString(ManyThings value) {
        //TODO: implement
        return value.toString();
    }

}

@Path("/")
public static class Service {
    @GET
    @Path("/stuff/")
    public int getStuffByThings(
        @QueryParam("things") ManyThings things){

        return things.things.size();
    }
}



@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    Dispatcher dispatcher = MockDispatcherFactory.createDispatcher();
    dispatcher.getProviderFactory().addStringConverter(new Converter());
    dispatcher.getRegistry().addSingletonResource(new Service());

    MockHttpRequest request = MockHttpRequest.get("/stuff?things=a,b,c");
    MockHttpResponse response = new MockHttpResponse();

    dispatcher.invoke(request, response);

    Assert.assertEquals("3", response.getContentAsString());


}
}
```

I think you can also use a [StringParamUnmarshaller](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.3.1.GA/userguide/html_single/index.html#StringParamUnmarshaller)

Answer (score 0):

I had some luck with this, using `Collection` rather than `List`. I was unable to make a `StringConverter` for `List` work.

```
@Provider
public class CollectionConverter implements StringConverter<Collection<String>> {

  public Collection<String> fromString(String string) {
    if (string == null) {
      return Collections.emptyList();
    }
    return Arrays.asList(string.split(","));
  }

  public String toString(Collection<String> values) {
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    boolean first = true;
    for (String value : values) {
      if (first) {
        first = false;
      } else {
        sb.append(",");
      }
      sb.append(value);
    }
    return sb.toString();
  }
}
```

I did the `toString` from my head. Be sure to write unit tests for it to verify. But of course, everything is easier and clearer when you use Guava. Can use `Joiner` and `Splitter`. Really handy.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a wrapper on its own, no need for anything else.

In your endpoint

```
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
@Path("/find")
@GET
MyResponse find(@QueryParam("ids") Wrapper ids);
```

And you wrapper looks like this :

```
public class Wrapper implements Serializable {
    private List<BigInteger> ids = Collections.emptyList();

    public String toString() {
        return Joiner.on(",")
                     .join(ids);
    }

    public List<BigInteger> get() {
        return ids;
    }

    public Wrapper(String s) {
        if (s == null) {
            ids = Collections.emptyList();
        }
        Iterable<String> splitted = Splitter.on(',')
                                            .split(s);
        Iterable<BigInteger> ids = Iterables.transform(splitted, Functionz.stringToBigInteger);
        this.ids = Lists.newArrayList(ids);
    }

    public Wrapper(List<BigInteger> ids) {
        this.ids = ids;
    }
}
```